# Dispose EF Context by reference(remotely), Memory Leak

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, memory-leaks, memory-profiling

MVC EF6

Hi, I couldn't find an answer to this anywhere so I'm posting my own question, I am trying to track down a memory leak, there are a lot of repeated strings in my application, the application I'm working with is REALLY BIG, it has A LOT of code.

I realized that every time a request is made we are creating a new DB Context instance, but we're never disposing it, so just to check that off my list and make sure everything is disposed.

Please don't post something like, just do this:

```
using(var context = new DbContext) {}
```

I CAN'T do that because the application is HUGE and the refactoring would take A LOT of time. One think I decided to do is Create a dictionary and then save the context during each request like this(Global asax):

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     if (User != null && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
     {
        ContextConfig.Dispose(Context.Items["UniqueRequestId"].ToString());
     }
  }

  protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     //Creating Unique Request ID
     Context.Items["UniqueRequestId"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
  }
```

Here I create a unique ID per request, and then at the end I dispose any context that has been created during that request(yes I know it should only be one per request, but they do create more than 1, but max I've seen is 2 so it's not so bad I guess).

This is my ContextConfig class:

```
public static class ContextConfig
{
  private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<DbContext>> Config = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<DbContext>>();

  public static void Add(string key, DbContext context)
  {
     //If contains key then add it, otherwise just create new instance
     if (Config.ContainsKey(key))
     {
        Config[key].Add(context);
     }
     else
     {
        Config[key] = new List<DbContext>();
        Config[key].Add(context);
     }
  }

  public static void Dispose(string key)
  {
     //If contains key and list has context then dispose them. 
     if (Config.ContainsKey(key))
     {
        if (Config[key] != null && Config[key].Count > 0)
           foreach (var context in Config[key])
           {
              context.Dispose();
           }

        Config[key].Clear();  
        ((IDictionary)Config).Remove(key);
     }
    }
   }
```

After this I was expecting to see an improvement in my MemoryLeak problem, but I think this somehow made it worse because for some reasons the instances I added to the list were being held by the garbage collector and now I'm lost.

This is what I see in the memory Profiling thing:

[image]

These are all the repeated strings:

[image]

**EDIT:** Not sure if this is relevant or not, but when I create a new instance, this happens

```
  context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
     context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
     context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

[image]

Comment: So, instead of searching every `DbContext` in your HUGE project and wrapping it in `using` block - you find every `DbContext` in yout HUGE project to add it to your reinvented weel?

Comment: @vasily.sib the way the code is structured makes it almost impossible to refactor

Comment: any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: even if this is _"almost impossible"_ you actualy do refactor it, don't you? Anyway, one thing you need to know about dictionary - it will not release allocated memory (basket) when you remove some item from it.

Comment: Using a static `ConcurrentDictionary` is not a great idea for this problem. If you really want to not do it properly using `using`, consider storing them in `HttpContext.Items` instead - that way it is at least scoped to the request (so it will be GCed eventually, while your approach here is quite likely to keep even more of them alive for longer than they are now).

Comment: When you say your code base is really big, how big **exactly**? 100 lines? 1000? 10000? 100000?

Comment: @mjwills I'm not using any IoC container, this is not using dependency Injection. 

I'm talking about more than 1 million lines of code, I had to buy a new computer just to open the project

Comment: Yeah, but I'll just go with your HttpContext.Items approuch and see if that helps

Comment: How do db contexts come to the ContextConfig ? The code shows only how they are removed.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov just as simple .add(context)

Comment: You are asking for help and aren't providing code which can be directly related to the problem. Without that it's not clear for example why contexts are removed for only authenticated users.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov Added a picture where I add the context, hope it helps

Comment: So question remains: why are contexts deleted with some conditions ?